# Autocomplete - only city

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-api

Do somebody know how I can filtring this autocomplete, that user recive only city name? like only: London, Paris and etc, without the other result : "London Bridge", "London eye" and etc - like in example.
I use in google places API Autocomplete,

so I use this code filter:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            synchronized (filterResults) {

                if (constraint != null) {
                    getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    result = mPlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    if (result != null) {
                        filterResults.values = result;
                        filterResults.count = result.size();
                    }
                }
                return filterResults;
```

and to get the only city name:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&types=(cities)");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVOEz.png)

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are building internet request, but if it is not necessary you can use google Places API. 
Here is Googles [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=en)

In your app you have to implement only few steps:

1)Build and connect google API client

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Activity.this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
    googleApiClient.connect();
```

2)Then you have few ways how to do: use autocomplete intent,  PlaceAutocompleteFragment or create `PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>`, get results from it and use it where you want. I had to use last one, so I created AutocompleteFilter

```
AutocompleteFilter.Builder builder = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
.setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES);
```

You can see AutocompleteFilter constants [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter)
Then I created PendingResult

```
PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> result
                        = Places
                        .GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, charSequence.toString(), null, builder.build());
```

And did what I needed in callback

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<AutocompletePredictionBuffer>{...});
```

In callback you can receive info in way like this:

```
Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    int size = autocompletePredictions.getCount();
                    if (status.isSuccess()){
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                            //Do what you need
                        }
                    }
```

Maybe it isnt the best way but it work for me and Its similar to building requests, like you did ( on my opinion). Anyway you can find how to do this the best for you in [guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete?hl=en).
Hope I helped you and sorry if I waste your time.

Comment: @Bon you got some errors here? If no, may you put breakpoint in place where you are trying to get data from result and watch what is here? And make sure that you connect GoogleApiClient in properly way.

Comment: I don't get a error message and I put breakpoint and he give me that filter is doing.. but still I dont get the filter only city.. I dont know what I miss and what I should do..

Comment: @Bon filter works good, I mean put break point inside callback and watch on result which you get

Comment: @Bon I added some code snippet to my response, hope it will help you

Comment: the breakpoint said "Object has been collected Cannot  evaluate android.os.Bundle.toString()..

Comment: another thing that I get from breakpoint is: mPlaceFilter= null, result = null

Comment: The MainActivity class :      protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();

Comment: I dont know why, but I didnt set Connection callback, maybe its because I used only Places.GEO_DATA_API and it work for me. May you also provide code from result callback?

Comment: Did it reach  `if(!status.isSuccess()) `?

Comment: idk then, maybe try callback

Comment: I try, this is my Callback:     private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e("place", "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;}
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);

Answer (score 0):

this is my code I need to get onlt city from the result autocomlete API google places: 
The MainActivity:

```
 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}

public void searchPlace(final Editable editable) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!editable.toString().equals("") && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    mAutoCompleteAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable.toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception");
```

The another Activity:  PlaceAPI

```
 public ArrayList<String> autocomplete (String input) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&types=(cities)");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

        URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
```

The adapter:

```
private ArrayList<String> result;


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            synchronized (filterResults) {

                if (constraint != null) {
                    getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    result = mPlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    if (result != null) {
                        filterResults.values = result;
                        filterResults.count = result.size();
                    }
                }
                return filterResults;
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, final FilterResults filterResults) {
            synchronized (filterResults) {

                mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (filterResults != null && filterResults.count >= 0) {
                            mResultList = resultList;
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } else {
                            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

This is what I add to AutocompletePredictionBuffer :

```
 private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
               Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                        mBounds, mPlaceFilter);


        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();

        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            autocompletePredictions.release();

            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
```